# Find $n$-th number in this sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a real life problem in which I need to find the $n^\text{th}$ number in the sequence below:

```
1  --->   0
2  --->   2
3  --->   6
4  --->   20
5  --->   70
6  --->   252
7  --->   924
8  --->   3432
9  --->   12870
```

Beyond the right side being divisible by $n$, I can't see the pattern or formula of getting from $n$ to the right side.

I can compute the value on the right side given an integer of $n$, so I can verify if someone, for example, knows what the value for $n=10$ should be.

Comment: "knows what the value for $n=10$ should be." Actually, there are several possibilities, see my answer.

Comment: No matter what the first nine or one thousand terms are, the answer to the question is “whatever”.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OEIS is often helpful: [Central binomial coefficients](https://oeis.org/A000984)

Comment: omg that was quick! Did you just recognise the sequence or what?

Comment: Well $252$ seemed familiar, but actually I just searched OEIS :D

Answer (score 3):

This is probably the central binomial coefficient
$$\binom{2n}{n} = \frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}. $$
On the other hand, it can also be a polynomial, namely
$$
f(x)=\frac{79x^8}{2880}−\frac{4583x^7}{5040}+\frac{3739x^6}{288}
−\frac{7409x^5}{72}+\frac{1413631x^4}{2880}
$$

$$
−\frac{1028681x^3}{720}
+\frac{117655x^2}{48} −\frac{62509x}{28}+810,
$$
which has values $f(1),f(2),\ldots ,f(9)$ as above. Here $f(10)=45480$, whereas $\binom{20}{10}=48620$.

Comment: Nice and clean!! (+1)

Comment: Oh, thank you!!